# Display animated sequence of images without blocking the interactive terminal

Tags: python, animation, ipython

I want to be able to display an animated sequence of images in Python without blocking the Python REPL. (The "sequence of images" is an array of static images). I've found a kludgy way of doing this, which is to launch a separate process which displays the animation using Tkinter. Launching a whole process in this way is quite inefficient in terms of memory.

Another way of putting this is, I want something like Pillow's `Image.show`, but which can display animations. Notice that `Image.show` launches a new window, and doesn't block the REPL.

Is there a non-kludgy way to do this?

Comment: Please be clearer on the exact expected behaviour. You want to start a program on the command line which pops up any sort of GUI (to display a GIF), but the called CLI command should finish immediately? Basically something like `nohup ... &`…?

Comment: @deceze I'm using an interactive terminal. Within that terminal, I generate multiple animations. I want to display these animations in separate windows, while still being able to use the terminal.

Comment: I apologise once again if I'm not being clear.

Comment: The behaviour I don't want is: The animation launches in a separate window, and then the terminal is blocked. I want to carry on using the terminal.

Comment: "Terminal" meaning the interactive Python REPL, yes? You should add that to the question. And focus less on the GIF part, as that's overall pretty irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to display a sequence of images as an animation using Matplotlib:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def display(images, title):
    """Display an animated sequence of images in a new window."""    
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(images[0].width/100,images[1].height/100))
    ims = []
    for i in range(len(images)):
        im = plt.imshow(images[i], animated=True)
        ims.append([im])
    ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=10, blit=True,
                                    repeat_delay=0)
    plt.axis('off')    
    plt.axis("tight")
    plt.axis("image")
    fig.tight_layout(pad=0)
    fig.canvas.set_window_title(title)
    plt.show()
```

This doesn't hog the terminal. It's still quite slow though.